# LinkedList...inheritance...what?

Tags: java

I don't understand what this homework is asking me to do...

In our last project, we created a person.java class that made an array of people (or just instances of people)...and it had their ID, their mom, their dad, birthdate, number of children, and an array of their children. It had predictable methods like get or set mom and dad, add child, remove child, unset mom or dad, boolean to see if another instance is or is not a child of this instance, get sex, get id...i think that was it.

Anyway...the point of this project is to make small changes to our last project to allow unlimited number of children for each person class. The last project had a static int variable for the maximum number of allowable children set to 10.

To do this, we're to implement a list. And create another class called personlist.java, which is to be a sublcass of java.util.LinkedList. We have to make sure to save Person.java in the same project where we create PersonList.java so that the compler can recognize java.util.LinkedList. The PersonList class should transparently handle all methods related to adding/removing/finding the children of a person. Since PersonList is a subclass of LinkedList, we will have all the LinkedList methods available to us.

I don't even know where to start. I still have my Person.java class. I'm using Eclipse...so I made a new project. Made a class called PersonList.java. Made another class called Person.java and copied my old project into it.

How do I declare the new class so that it "communicates" with Person.java?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class PersonList extends LinkedList<Person> {

}
```

Is that right? I'm also confused as to why we weren't told to just modify Person.java to utilize linked lists. I can do that. Why create another class called PersonList.java? And what the heck goes in there? How do I call methods in PersonList.java from Person.java?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shakedown - Am I declaring it wrong? I'm honestly confused.

Comment: I think it's just a Brady Bunch reference. Feel free to ignore it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Switch you're children variable in the Person class to be of type LinkedList.

```
public class Person {
    ....
    private LinkedList<Person> children;
    ....
 }
```

Unless you're leaving out part of the problem there's no need whatsoever to extend the LinkedList class.  In this instance you want composition rather than inheritance.

Oh and when you submit your assignment tell your professor why you picked your solution.

Comment: except that the homework is supposed to be about learning both linked lists and inheritance. now...granted...i just started programming last semester...but inheritance seems to not make a great deal of sense here, i just can't wrap my head around it for this exercise.

Comment: @marsha: You're quite right to suggest it doesn't make sense. Inheritance should only be used to EXTEND functionality-- for example, if you wanted to find a person by their name, that's something specific to a PersonList and one approach is to extend LinkedList and add a new method (while keeping the other LinkedList methods for free). But just for reusing the same functionality, there's not a lot of point except to just familiarize yourself with the syntax.

Comment: @Platinum Azure - that's a fair point about adding functionality i.e. search by name.  What would worry me would be if the poster tried to subclass and override the LinkedList methods to accept Person additions/removals which would be unnecessary...  

I'd also avoid extending the LinkedList<Person> generic type and directly extend LinkedList.  Type erasure will remove the <Person> type parameter and leave you with a LinkedList (I think...)

Comment: I think you're right. The main thrust of my point (above) was that inheritance is pointless when all you're really trying to do is completely reuse it. But the original poster is doing this as part of a homework assignment, and some of us can remember how pointless (and sometimes outright harmful, in terms of teaching bad practice or not explaining good practice fully) the homework assignments can be.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` is not designed for inheritance. **Forwarding** to better than inheritance.

Comment: what do you mean by Forwarding? aggregation?